# Creating an Index with English Analyzer using Nest

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am using nest to create my Elasticsearch Index. I have two questions:

*Question 1. How can I add the settings to use english analyzer with a fall back for Standard Analyzer?*

This is how I am creating my Index:

```
Uri _node = new Uri("elasticUri");
ConnectionSettings _connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(_node)
            .DefaultIndex("MyIndexName")
            .DefaultMappingFor<POCO>(m => m
            .IndexName("MyIndexName")
        );
IElasticClient _elasticClient = new ElasticClient(_connectionSettings);

var createIndexResponse = _elasticClient.CreateIndex("MyIndexName", c => c
   .Mappings(m => m
      .Map<POCO>(d => d.AutoMap())
   )
);
```

Looking at the examples [Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html), I am also not sure what should I pass for **"english_keywords"**, **"english_stemmer"**, etc

*Question 2*: If I use English Analyzer, will Elasticsearch automatically realize that the terms: "Barbecue" and "BBQ" are synonyms? Or do I need to explicitly pass a list of Synonyms to ES?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the NEST documentation for [configuring a built-in analyzer for an index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/writing-analyzers.html#_configuring_a_built_in_analyzer).

The [documentation for the `english` analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html#english-analyzer) simply demonstrates how you *could* reimplement the `english` analyzer yourself, as a custom analyzer, with the built-in analysis components, if you need to customize any part of the analysis. If you don't need to do this, simply use `english` as the name for the analyzer for a field

```
client.CreateIndex("my_index", c => c
    .Mappings(m => m
        .Map<POCO>(mm => mm
            .AutoMap()
            .Properties(p => p
                .Text(t => t
                    .Name(n => n.MyProperty)
                    .Analyzer("english")
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Will use the built-in `english` analyzer for the `MyProperty` field on `POCO`.

The `english` analyzer will not perform automatic synonym expansion for you, you'll need to configure the synonyms that are relevant to your search problem. You have two choices with regards to synonyms

1. Perform synonym expansion at index time on the index input. This will result in faster search at the expense of being a relatively fixed approach.
2. Perform synonym expansion at query time on the query input. This will result in slower search, but affords the flexibility to more easily add new synonym mappings as and when you need to.

You can always take the approach of using both, that is, indexing the synonyms that you expect to be relevant to your search use case, and adding new synonyms at query time, as you discover them to be relevant to your use case.

Comment: Thanks a lot Russ. Would I achieve the same by putting: [Text(Analyzer = "english")] attribute on MyProperty in the POCO class?

Comment: If I take the first approach, is there a standard list of common synonyms that I could download and use?

Comment: Using the attribute will work, you will also need to call `AutoMap()` for the attribute to be taken into account. Regarding synonyms, that's a very wide question. There are common data sets like WordNet (https://wordnet.princeton.edu/) that can be used. Be sure to also have a read of the Definitive Guide re: synonyms (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/synonyms.html)